# How to control more than one selects adding and removing options

Tags: reactjs, select

I have six different selects in my code, all of them start with the same pool of options (they share the same array).

I want that when I select an option, it gets removed from the pool of options and therefore from the other selects so they can't be repeated . And if the option gets deselected it will be added back to the pool.

I can remove the selected option from the pool of options, but then it becomes an out-of-range value and I can't display it back into the options that are still not selected.

My code looks like this:

```
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([
        '--',
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5',
        '6',
    ])
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState({
        box1: '--',
        box2: '--',
        box3: '--',
        box4: '--',
        box5: '--',
        box6: '--',
    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target

        setSelectedValue({
            ...selectedValue,
            [name]: value
        })

        const index = options.indexOf(value)
        const newData = options
        newData.splice(index, 1)

        setOptions(newData)
    }

               <Box className={classes.columnBox}>
                  <TextField
                        select name='box1'
                        value={selectedValue.box1}
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {options.map(option => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </TextField>
                </Box>
                <Box className={classes.columnBox}>
                    <Typography>{selectedValue.box2}</Typography>
                    <TextField
                        select name='box2'
                        value={selectedValue.box2}
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {options.map(option => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </TextField>
                </Box>
                <Box className={classes.columnBox}>
                    <Typography>{selectedValue.box3}</Typography>
                    <Select
                        name='box3'
                        value={selectedValue.box3}
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {options.map(option => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </Box>
                <Box className={classes.columnBox}>
                    <Typography>{selectedValue.box4}</Typography>
                    <Select
                        name='box4'
                        value={selectedValue.box4}
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {options.map(option => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </Box>
                <Box className={classes.columnBox}>
                    <Typography>{selectedValue.box5}</Typography>
                    <Select
                        name='box5'
                        value={selectedValue.box5}
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {options.map(option => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </Box>
                <Box className={classes.columnBox}>
                    <Typography>{selectedValue.box6}</Typography>
                    <Select
                        name='box6'
                        value={selectedValue.box6}
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {options.map(option => {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </Box>
```

This is basically what I'm trying to recreate:
[As you can see, the options are not displayed if I have them already selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBGFr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out how many things are changing and when they are changing.
Options and the selected value for a single select, change on selection.

So these will be our state variables.
Since our options are shared among selects, and we might also be interested in all the selected values once the user is done selecting, so we need to lift'em up.

Our options will contain a value which we can use to remove the selection, let's say its '--'

```
const [remainingOptions, setRemainingOptions] = useState([])
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({})
```

Whenever the user selects:

```
const onSelect = (index, newValue) => {
  setSelected(prev => ({ ...prev, [index]: newValue })) 
}
```

To update remaingingOptions we use a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const selectedOptions = Object.keys(selected).map((selectIndex) => selected[selectIndex])
  const uniqueSelections = [...new Set(selectedOptions)]
  
  setRemainingOptions(allOptions.filter(option => uniqueSelections.indexOf(option) === -1 || option === '--'))
}, [selected])
```

Now if the user deselects something by selecting '--' in any select, the `remainingOptions` will be recalculated based on the selected values in remaining `select` tags.

We can use this `remainingOptions` state variable in all our selects, and pass the `onSelect` as prop to `select` tags.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, but I'm having some difficult implementing it. I'm using Material UI and the Select has only a prop "onChange", and it does not pass a index. Where I should use the "onSelect" so it can work properly?

Comment: I managed to make it work, but it falls in the same problem I was having where I can't show the value in the select because it isn't a option anymore. But thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it and helped me learn some cool new things!!